Name clash for '<p..\build\Jam\...>name.obj', incompatible properties: none
When I try to use the obj rule in B2, like this:
obj name : $(CPP_FILES) ;
I get this error which I have a hard time understanding:
error: Name clash for '<p..\build\Jam\...>name.obj'
error:
error: Tried to build the target twice, with property sets having
error: these incompatible properties:
error:
error:     -  none
error:     -  none
error:
error: Please make sure to have consistent requirements for these
error: properties everywhere in your project, especially for install
error: targets.

What does it mean ?

As the doc says:

obj
Creates an object file. Useful when a single source file must be compiled with special properties.

You are probably trying to build a single obj from multiple .cpp source files.
